# UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://")!) always returns true

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I need to check whether the user has installed Google Maps on the phone . If Google Maps is installed, open Google Maps, else open Apple Maps. 
But even when Google Maps is not installed 'canOpenURL' returns true.

Here’s my code,

```
if (UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "comgooglemaps://")!)){
        let urlString = "comgooglemaps://?center=" + lat + "," + long + "&q=" + lat + "," + long
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
    }else{
        let urlString:NSString = NSString(format: "http://maps.apple.com/?q=%@,%@", lat, long)
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: urlString as String)!)
    }
```

And, I have added LSApplicationQueriesSchemes array and appended "comgooglemaps" to it.

[image: Info.plist Image here]

Comment: what is the question in this case?

Comment: hey, even when Google Maps is not installed on the device 'canOpenURL' returns true.

Comment: Hi, I just tested your code and also deleting the google maps app from the device. It works fine. Are you testing this on the real device or simulator? Everything seems to be working like it is supposed to

Comment: its working fine...

Comment: On a real device.
But when I delete google maps from the device, the button just shows the click , but nothing happens.

Comment: My iOS version is 10.3.2. Is it something to do with that?

Comment: Have you made sure that you restart the application after deleting google maps?

Comment: yes, did that too

Comment: i am too getting same issue on iOS 11.3